# How to access Calender in windows Phone 8.1 Universal app

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I am looking for some example how to access windows phone calender in windows phone 8.1 universal app. I found an artical on how to read calender data but it is in windows phone 8.1 Silverlight.

Is there any way to read calendar in windows phone 8.1 Universal app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Appointments Concepts to work with Calendar events inside Windows Universal Application.

appointmentStore = await AppointmentManager.RequestStoreAsync(AppointmentStoreAccessType.AppCalendarsReadWrite);

For more information you can check here,  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn631243.aspx